# Incongruencia en tipo de dato de columna de tabla sql server

Tags: sql-server

mi problema es que en una tabla de sql server con datos he cambiado el tipo de dato de una columna que estaba como int a nchar. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que ahora edito la tabla y al intentar modicar ese campo en algún registro y meter caracteres me da error de conflicto porque intento guardar un nchar en un int.
Es como si por debajo el cambio del tipo de dato no se hubiera hecho en la tabla aunque si miras en el diseño de la tabla si que aparece el campo como nchar.
El cambio lo hice con un alter column y lo hizo correctamente.

Esto ya lo he hecho otras veces y nunca me dió este problema.

[image: campo de la tabla modificado]

[image: Error al modificar campo]

Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
Gracias!!!

Comment: Si la ventana del explorador de consultas, la tenías abierta es posible, que este cacheado, y no sepa que es un int. Prueba a Ctrl + May + R (Intellisense cache local), y realiza las updates en una nueva ventana.

Comment: Gracias Javi fer2, pero no, incluso cierro el sql server pero nada. Es más, esa tabla la tengo vinculada a un access y desde el access me dice lo mismo aunque también me muestra que el campo es tipo texto

Comment: Otra solución, seria que agregues un campo nuevo de nchar y ahi pases los datos que ya tienes una vez que lo tengas asi, haces update a ver si te deja si es asi, ahora borras el campo antiguo y puedes remombrar el otro como estaba el anterior.

Comment: UPs. entonces el problema esta en la vinculación. Esos metadatos no se actualizan y por eso no te funciona. Quita la misma, refresca y vincula de nuevo. Seguro que así se te arregla.

Comment: Gracias a los dos, pero sigo igual. He hecho lo que has dicho Edgar, pero no sé como hace pero cuando he creado el nuevo campo y copiado los datos del original me dejaba modificar el nuevo, pero en cuanto he hecho el cambio de nombre al campo, otra vez me da el conflicto. También he desvinculado esta tabla del access y la he vuelto a vincular pero nada. De alguna forma ese nombre del campo está vinculado a algo y no hay forma

Comment: Pregúntale a Information_schema.Columns where table_name = xxxx and column_name = yyyy. Luego puedes ir recorriendo las vistas de information_schema y alguna te tiene que decir que algo no está donde debe. Siempre pensando en que está vinculado. Ya comentas

Comment: Otra cosa. Por retroceder un paso. Porque no pegas una update en una ventana del management studio, y aquí para que le echemos un vistazo, no vaya a ser que el mensaje no tenga que ver con lo que ocurre. Por ejemplo copia una fila (o al menos unos campos significativos, donde esté incluido ese) y la definición de la tabla que te devuelve el management studio y lo miramos desde otra perspectiva.

Comment: arriba, en la pregunta puse dos pantallazos, uno con la definición del campo en la tabla y otro con el error que da cuando intento modificar

Comment: ya encontré el problema. Esa tabla tenía un trigger que hacía un update en otra tabla que a su vez tenía otro trigger que hacía referencia a ese campo pero lo guardaba en una variable que era int. Gracias a todos!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema. Esa tabla tenía un trigger que hacía un update en otra tabla que a su vez tenía otro trigger que hacía referencia a ese campo pero lo guardaba en una variable que era int